# In firestore, Is it possible to retrieve the data type of a field, if I specify the document and the field?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to write a custom admin for my firebase web application. I did check [the api docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore) and I of course checked [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=firebase%20firestore%20field%20data%20type) also. In theory, of course this is possible, but afaik, firestore does not appear to offer an api for this purpose. But I may be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firestore is a schemaless database. This means it doesn't have a schema for the entire database, but it does of course have type information for the fields in a specific document.

To determine the type of a field, you have to [get the document from database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data), get the field from the document snapshot ([Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot#get(java.lang.String)), [iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/DocumentSnapshot#get_:), [Web](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot#get)), and then use the type system of your platform to detect the type.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your exact usage, you can also open the Firestore view in the google console (by clicking on the "More in Google Cloud" button in the firebase console), and select the "Data" view in the left menu. This allows you to browse the Firestore data.

You can then go to one of the documents, click on the 3 dots on the right and select "Add similar document". This opens a view with all the fields of the document, their types, and the hierarchy between them. This can be copied as text and fed to chat gpt to create a "database schema" or a json file of the structure that you can reuse (for building a schema view in BigQuery for example).

Add similar document button: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbUXS.png

A note:
As with all non-schema databases, all documents probably do not contain the same fields, so the document you selected might not contain all the different fields you use, so be sure to add the other ones.